# Can the JEDI Code Library, Delphi IDE menu item (JCL Options...), be moved?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, jedi

Is there a way to move the Delphi IDE menu item Tools->JCL Options..., to the bottom of the tools menu?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `JclOtaActions.pas`, in `TJclOTAActionExpert.RegisterCommands` it registers the menu item:

```
ToolsMenuItem.Insert(0, FConfigurationMenuItem);
```

I think if you change it to:

```
ToolsMenuItem.Add(FConfigurationMenuItem);
```

Then it will at the bottom.

Hope this points you in the right direction...

Comment: I think it should be locating the first separator item in the menu and inserting itself above that separator. The last part of the menu is for Tools configured in the "configure tools" screen. I really hope that moving this item down there doesn't cause any screwiness in the IDE, but it might NOT be safe to do this even though the OP likes it better.